# Scaling with DB-based session store / Users table in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, session, activerecord, scaling

In Rails 4, the ActiveRecord based session store was ripped out into a gem and deprecated - one of the reasons why was stated in this snippet:

> In past versions of Rails, different storage mechanisms were added to
>   the core framework to handle this limitation, such as the Active
>   Record and Memcached session stores. However, one major issue with the
>   Active Record session store is that it is not scalable. It puts an
>   unnecessary load on your database. Once your application receives a
>   large amount of traffic, the sessions database table is continuously
>   bombarded with read/write operations.

My question is... doesn't the same problem occur with something common such as the Users table?

Say hypothetically, that you have a large number of users, and a large amount of traffic, and every action that each user does requires a read and a write to the user table.  Won't this introduce the same sort of read/write contention?

How does one scale to address this?

Thanks!